# Replace x with y or append y if no x

Tags: python, regex

If a string contains `foo`, replace `foo` with `bar`. Otherwise, append `bar` to the string. How to write this with one single `re.sub` (or any other function) call? No conditions or other logic.

```
import re

regex = "????"
repl  = "????" 

assert re.sub(regex, repl, "a foo b")       == "a bar b"
assert re.sub(regex, repl, "a foo b foo c") == "a bar b bar c"
assert re.sub(regex, repl, "afoob")         == "abarb"
assert re.sub(regex, repl, "spam ... ham")  == "spam ... hambar"
assert re.sub(regex, repl, "spam")          == "spambar"
assert re.sub(regex, repl, "")              == "bar"
```

For those curious, in my application I need the replacement code to be table-driven - regexes and replacements are taken from the database.

Comment: doesn't "x OR not x" replace everything?

Comment: @Anirudh: added one more example

Comment: Depending how complex this gets, and how far you end up attempting to stretch regex's, you may also wish to consider storing code objects instead - then using those.

Comment: what about "afoochuk" (when "foo" is not surrounded by space)?

Comment: @doubleDown: whitespace doesn't matter.

Comment: regexp is sometimes an overkill and sometimes just makes everything more complicated, and slow. Many of the times you'll find a non-re, faster solution.

Comment: @Anirudh Can you undelete your answer please? While it might not be a valid solution for Python, it still contains a lot of helpful information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is tricky. In Python, replacement text backreferences to groups that haven't participated in the match [are an error](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html), so I had to build quite a convoluted construction using [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but it seems to pass all the test cases:

```
result = re.sub("""(?sx)
    (              # Either match and capture in group 1:
     ^             # A match beginning at the start of the string
     (?:(?!foo).)* # with all characters in the string unless foo intervenes
     $             # until the end of the string.
    |              # OR
     (?=foo)       # The empty string right before "foo"
    )              # End of capturing group 1
    (?:foo)?       # Match foo if it's there, but don't capture it.""", 
                     r"\1bar", subject)
```

Comment: Oops, I get an error in some cases. Will have to work on it, but I have to be off to a lecture now. Later...

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. This was a very interesting problem. Thanks!

Comment: `^((?:(?!foo).)*)(?:foo)?` is all you need.  When the first part runs out of stuff it can match, the next thing can only be `foo` or the end of the string.

Comment: @AlanMoore: You're right, but only if there is no more than one `foo` in the string. Maybe without the `^`...let me check...no, that won't work.

Comment: Ayuh, I should have looked more closely at the examples.  The question doesn't give any hint that there could be more than one `foo`.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work well. An interesting way to work around limitations of the re module.

Answer (score 9):

Try this simple one-liner, no regexp, no tricks:

```
a.replace("foo", "bar") + (a.count("foo") == 0) * "bar"
```

Comment: This seems to me the only sensible solution; there are situations where regexes aren't the best tool - this is one of those.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems he does need a regex (see the last sentence from his question).

Comment: @TimPietzcker - so he can define a function for this: `def my_nonre_sub(x, y, z):
 return z.replace(x, y) + (z.count(x) == 0) * y`

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP asked for regex **"or any other function"**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

regex:

```
^(?!.*foo)(.*)$|foo(\b)
```

or

```
foo|^(?!.*foo)(.*)$
```

replace with:`\1bar`

works [here](http://regexr.com?35b0f)

Comment: This fails on strings with multiple words like `one two three` (result: `onebar twobar threebar`).

Comment: I always remove my downvote, when the reason for it is gone. Now your answer is very similar to what @Tim had in his deleted version. He mentioned that he had errors for some cases, I don't know what it could be, hope he is coming back to this question when he is available again and explain his edge cases...

Comment: Tim is the No. 1 regex answerer here, if he posts an answer it is normally working. And **I tried his answer the same way I tested yours. And if you add the missing closing bracket you forgot after `$` in your link, then it will work also for you.**

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work with Python. `re.sub(r'\bfoo\b|^(?!.*\bfoo\b)(.*)$', r'\1bar', 'a foo b')` bails out with `unmatched group`

Comment: @Anirudh, no it does not, just add another newline, otherwise `$` will not match. [Regexr](http://regexr.com?35b03)

Comment: @1_CR I really have no idea about python

Comment: @Anirudh, the OP's question is tagged `python`. Additionally, I see that your solution performs a group replacement, but there is no capturing group defined for the case where `foo` features in the input string.

Comment: @1_CR in that case group 1 returns **empty** string

Comment: @Anirudh, unfortunately that doesn't appear to be the way the python regex engine sees it. It bails out with an error as stated earlier

Comment: `re.sub('\bfoo\b|^(?!.*\bfoo\b)(.*)$', '\\1bar', x)` works for me; except that it doesn’t replace `foo` in the first 4 cases (but just appends `bar`).

Comment: @Anirudh With the changed expression, 3–5 are correct now; in 1 and 2 nothing changes… odd.

Comment: @poke, you need to "raw-string" `\bfoo\b|^(?!.*\bfoo\b)(.*)$`, otherwise the `\b`s are not handled correctly. Check the `re.sub` examples from the documentation

Comment: @1_CR i removed `\b` since op has never specified that foo is a separate word

Comment: @1_CR Yeah, you’re right, I was wrong. I do get that unmatched group error as well. I tried adding an additional group to the simple case, but apparently Python numbers them all individually and will raise an error when the first group (depending on order) is never matched…

Comment: @Anirudh Unfortunately it does not, because `\1` always refers to `(.*)`, while `\2` would refer to the `(\b)`.

Comment: FYI: There is a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1519638) about it, and a [solution](http://bugs.python.org/issue2636) (a new `re` module) that will apparently make it into Python in 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

A two liner inspired by @zenpoy:

```
ar =  a.replace("foo", "bar") 
a + 'bar' if a is ar else ar
```

Comment: this should be: `a + 'bar' if a is a.replace("foo", "bar") else a.replace("foo", "bar")` which is calling replace twice...

Comment: @zenpoy, thanks, I had originally a two liner, but over optimized it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the weird cousin?

```
re.sub(regex, repl, str) if re.match(regex,str) else str + repl
```

Or the fat cousin?

```
(str + repl, re.sub(regex, repl, str))[bool(re.match(regex, str))]
```

Both are less cryptic, though admittedly both have additional function calls and logic compared to [Tim's excellent regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274252/1743811).